# why first li element dont move down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            ul,li {
                position:relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="c1">This is 1</li>
             <li class="c2">This is 2</li>
             <li class="c3">This is 3</li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <button>Move</button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("button").on("click",function(){
                $c = $(".c2").clone(true);
                $c.attr({class:""});
                $c.insertAfter(".c2");
                var y = $(".c2").position();
                var x = ($(".c2").insertBefore(".c1")).position();
                $(".c2").hide();
                $c.css({position:"absolute"}).animate({"top":x.top,"left":x.left},{duration:1000});
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

why `<li class="c1">This is 1</li>` dont move down? and overlay with `<li class="c2">This is 2</li>` ?

Comment: did you check the answer?

Comment: yes,tank you.Dekel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You positioned the second `li` element as `absolute`, so it overlap the first element.

This is the result of html (after you clicked the button):

```css
ul,li {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="c2" style="display: none;">This is 2</li>
  <li class="c1">This is 1</li>
  <li class="" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 40px;">This is 2</li>
  <li class="c3">This is 3</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to swap between the two elements you can use this code do to so:

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
  c1pos = $(".c1").position();
  c2pos = $(".c2").position();
  
  $c1 = $(".c1").clone(true);
  $c1.attr({class:""});
  $c1.insertAfter(".c1");
    
  $c2 = $(".c2").clone(true);
  $c2.attr({class:""});
  $c2.insertAfter(".c2");
  
  $(".c1,.c2").css('visibility', 'hidden');
  
  $c1.css({position:"absolute", "top":c1pos.top,"left":c1pos.left},{duration:1000});
  $c2.css({position:"absolute", "top":c2pos.top,"left":c2pos.left},{duration:1000});
  
  $c1.css({position:"absolute"}).animate({"top":c2pos.top,"left":c2pos.left},{duration:1000});
  $c2.css({position:"absolute"}).animate({"top":c1pos.top,"left":c1pos.left},{duration:1000});
})
```

```css
ul,li {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="c1">This is 1</li>
  <li class="c2">This is 2</li>
  <li class="c3">This is 3</li>
</ul>

<button>Move</button>
```